# How can I grant individual permissions for user in IAM for Bigquery using python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I want to give below IAM permission for the user.

Permission:

> BigQuery Job User
>   Browser

I know How I can set through windows UI but I want to set this IAM permission through a python script?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do so by using the [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/quickstart-client-libraries).

You can check some examples in the [following documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#using_gcloud_rest_api_or_client_libraries).

I made a quick script that does what you are requesting:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery


credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    filename='PATH/TO/KEY.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    'cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials)



def modify_policy_add_member(policy, role, member):
    binding = next(b for b in policy['bindings'] if b['role'] == role)
    binding['members'].append(member)
    print(binding)
    return policy

def create_role_add_member(policy, role, member):
    """Adds a new member to a role binding."""
    binding = {
                'role': role,
                'members': [member]
            }
    print(binding)
    policy['bindings'].append(binding)
    return policy

if __name__ == "__main__":
    project_id="YOUR_PROJECT_ID"
    policy=service.projects().getIamPolicy(
                resource=project_id,
                body={},
            ).execute()
    role="roles/bigquery.dataViewer" #example role to grant user
    member="user:MEMBER_TO_ADD"
    roles = [b['role'] for b in policy['bindings']]
    if role  in roles:
        new_policy = modify_policy_add_member(policy, role, member)
    else:
        new_policy = create_role_add_member(policy, role, member)
    print(new_policy)
    policy = service.projects().setIamPolicy(
            resource=project_id,
            body={
                'policy': new_policy,
    }).execute()
```

Breaking it down by parts, the script does the following:

1- Authenticate to the API by using a Service Account key file, with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` scopes. I used a service account key file with `project/owner` permissions, in this example.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    filename='PATH/TO/KEY.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    'cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
```

2- Get the current policy of the project:

```
 policy=service.projects().getIamPolicy(
                resource=project_id,
                body={},
            ).execute()
```

3- Set the role to grant, which in BigQuery you can see in [this list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#roles). As well, set the member to add, in the format `user:<USER_ADDRESS>`, you need to keep the string `user:` before the account to add, unless you are adding a service account, then you must change `user:` to `serviceaccount:`.

4- Check if the role already exists, if it does, just append the member to the existing role:

```
def modify_policy_add_member(policy, role, member):
    binding = next(b for b in policy['bindings'] if b['role'] == role)
    binding['members'].append(member)
    print(binding)
    return policy
```

Otherwise, create the role and append it to the policy bindings:

```
def create_role_add_member(policy, role, member):
    """Adds a new member to a role binding."""
    binding = {
                'role': role,
                'members': [member]
            }
    print(binding)
    policy['bindings'].append(binding)
    return policy
```

5- Update the policy in your project, by sending the updated policy:

```
policy = service.projects().setIamPolicy(
            resource=project_id,
            body={
                'policy': new_policy,
    }).execute()
```

Note that to use this APIs in Python, you will need to install the following modules:

```
google-api-python-client==1.7.4
google-auth==1.5.1
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
```